# Can you use .net 3.5 Action or Func as Marshalled unmanaged delegates?

Tags: .net-3.5, delegates, pinvoke, marshalling, anonymous-methods

After reading  [Dynamically calling unmanaged dlls in .net](http://blogs.msdn.com/jonathanswift/archive/2006/10/03/Dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-.NET-_2800_C_23002900_.aspx)

I've been trying to modify the code to my liking. I made a class that implements idisposable to wrap load calls in and free them when needed. However I can't seem to figure out the syntax if it is possible to use anonymous delegates with it.

```
var loaded=DynamicLibraryLoader.TryLoad("User32.dll");
var beeper=loaded.GetProcAddress("MessageBeep");
var type=typeof(Action<UInt32>);
Action<UInt32> beepAction2=(Action<UInt32>) Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(beeper,type);
```

The last line throws an argument exception saying that the specified Type must not be a generic type definition. Is there a way around this or do I have to provide a named delegate to do anything unmanaged?

For reference of any interested in what you can do by default in windows with unmanaged code - [Link](http://pinvoke.net/index.aspx)  (create shortcuts,dynamically load a DLL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the exception indicates, you must use a non-generic delegate when converting a native function pointer to managed code.

Comment: so there's no syntax or way around it?

Comment: @Maslow, no there is not at this time

Comment: I guess since there are no other answers, I'll accept the answer that just reads back to me what the exception says, I would have preferred some resources,reference or some type of workaround ideas.

Comment: @Maslow, unfortunately there's not much more to give.  It's simply an unsupported scenario at this point