# Create Delegate Type Non-Generic

Tags: c#, types, delegates, marshalling

```
static void CallUnmanageFunction(string dllName, string functionName, params object[] parameters)
    {
        IntPtr dllHandle = LoadLibrary(dllName);
        IntPtr functionHandle = GetProcAddress(dllHandle, functionName);
        List<Type> typeParameters = new List<Type>();
        foreach (object p in parameters)
        {
            typeParameters.Add(p.GetType());
        }
        Type type = Expression.GetDelegateType(typeParameters.ToArray());         
        Delegate function = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(functionHandle, type);
        function.DynamicInvoke(parameters);
    }

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CallUnmanageFunction("user32.dll", "MessageBoxA", IntPtr.Zero, "Es funktioniert", "Test", (uint)0);
    }
```

I want to call an unmanaged function by giving the libraryname and the functionname as a string and the parameters as normal types (params object[] parameters).
The function "GetDelegateForFunctionPointer" expects a non-generic delegate type, but the function "GetDelegateType" of the "Expression" class gives a generic "Action" or "Func"-Delegate. Has somebody any idea for solving this problem?

Sorry for my bad english, its my worst subject at school.
Thank you very much in advance for your answer! :)

Comment: Why not use `MessageBox.Show`?

Comment: I guess that was just an example.

Comment: Hmmm... This compiles for me. What error do you get?

Comment: Its a runtime error: The specified type must not be a generic type definition. I create a delegate at the runtime, so of course this compiles perfectly, the problem is: i call GetDelegateType which creates a generic delegate type (see Action<T> and Func<T>). The question is: Is there another way to call unmanaged function dynamically?

Comment: @PMF. If you want to reproduce this problem you need to adjust the DLLImport attribute to [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]

Using CharSet = CharSet.Ansi

Comment: And perhaps taking a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347484/can-you-use-net-3-5-action-or-func-as-marshalled-unmanaged-delegates will help.

Comment: See topic: [C# GetDelegateForFunctionPointer with generic delegate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699394/c-sharp-getdelegateforfunctionpointer-with-generic-delegate)