# C# GetDelegateForFunctionPointer with generic delegate

Tags: c#

I need to dynamically invoke dll function.

I'm using standard windows API to load dll and get proc address.

After I retrieve proc's IntPtr I try to convert it to delegate:

```
Func<int> inv = (Func<int>)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(proc, typeof(Func<int>));
```

But it fails because typeof(Func) return generics type.

Is there any clean way to accomplish what I'm trying to do without just declaring member delegate and
use it as type ?

I mean I'm trying to avoid the following redundancy:

```
//I need this member only for typeof operator
private delegate int RunDll();
RunDll inv = (RunDll)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(proc, typeof(RunDll));
```

Answer (score 8):

It would be worse if the delegate type was dynamic and you didn't know the parameters. Then you could use .NET methods to generate it.

```
public static class DelegateCreator
{
    private static readonly Func<Type[],Type> MakeNewCustomDelegate = (Func<Type[],Type>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<Type[],Type>), typeof(Expression).Assembly.GetType("System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.DelegateHelpers").GetMethod("MakeNewCustomDelegate", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static));

    public static Type NewDelegateType(Type ret, params Type[] parameters)
    {
        Type[] args = new Type[parameters.Length];
        parameters.CopyTo(args, 0);
        args[args.Length-1] = ret;
        return MakeNewCustomDelegate(args);
    }
}
```

```
DelegateCreator.NewDelegateType(typeof(int)) //returns non-generic variant of Func<int>
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed, a non-generic delegate type creator so I can call Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate on it. :)

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zdx6dyyh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) generics simply aren't supported by this API.  Note that this isn't a great loss - after all, you need to specify the signature just once; the only disadvantage is that you cannot specify it inline - using `Func<int>` doesn't require that indirection, but (due to the cast) it's in a sense actually more redundant.

Incidentally, you may want to look at plain old [`DllImport`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26thfadc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - if the DLL and function are known ahead of time, you don't need to do this manual delegate wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

The original question here was (probably) best answered by `DllImport`, but the discussion inspired [NativeGenericDelegates](https://github.com/monkey0506/native-generic-delegates).

This project aims to provide `System.Delegate` objects that have a generic interface, can be used with P/Invoke, and may be invoked from both managed and unmanaged code with an `Invoke` method that doesn't rely on `DynamicInvoke`.

The calling convention of the unmanaged function pointer is explicitly specified by all methods, and custom marshaling behavior for the return value and parameters is optionally supported.

The (broken) code from the question:

```
Func<int> inv = (Func<int>)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(proc, typeof(Func<int>));
```

Could be implemented using:

```
var inv = INativeFunc<int>.FromFunctionPointer(proc, CallingConvention.Cdecl); // update calling convention as needed
int result = inv.Invoke(); // invoke the native function
Func<int> invFunc = inv.ToFunc(); // convert to Func<int> for use with other APIs
```

Details on more complex method signatures (including marshaling and modified signatures) are included in the project repo and source files.

**Edit:** I have just pushed an early version of an incremental generator for NativeGenericDelegates to the [incremental-generator](https://github.com/monkey0506/native-generic-delegates/tree/incremental-generator) branch of the repo. This is not yet feature-complete, but does not rely on `System.Reflection.Emit`, which means that it should support AOT platforms, unlike the previous version.

Comment: This is a cool contribution, but it's also important to note that it uses `System.Reflection.Emit` under the hood - something that's not available on certain platforms.

Comment: That's a fair point to make. It's similarly worth noting that `System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.DelegateHelpers.MakeNewCustomDelegate` referenced in other answers is a simpler version of the same code, also relying on `System.Reflection.Emit`, making neither of these a viable option for platforms that don't support dynamic code.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I only made this comment here because `System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler` relying on code generation is largely common knowledge, whereas in case of your library that might not be so obvious (at least it wasn't for me).

Comment: There is a note at the end of the README that mentions `System. Reflection.Emit`. I can make a more explicit notice near the top of the file. Understandably it would be frustrating to only realize this restriction after attempting to implement the code. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @julx if you are interested, I have been working on learning how to author a source generator. Functions that don't require marshalling should work on all .NET platforms through compile-time inference of the concrete type parameters.

Comment: Thank you for reaching out. I managed to get a work-around working for the particular use-case that I was interested in. But of course always interested to learn something new.

Comment: A lot of my work is hobby-based with a heavy focus in code reusability (generics), but our previous exchange here was the reason that I opted to move away from dynamic code and learn how to author a source generator instead.

Answer (score 0):

At first: **the implementation of method DelegateCreator.NewDelegateType isn't correct!**

```
public static Type NewDelegateType(Type ret, params Type[] parameters) {
  /*
  Type[] args = new Type[parameters.Length];   // Create "args" array of same length as "parameters" (must be length + 1)
  parameters.CopyTo(args, 0);                  // Copy all values of parameters to "args" array
  args[args.Length - 1] = ret;                 // Put "ret" value to last item of "args" array
  return MakeNewCustomDelegate(args);
  */
  var offset = parameters.Length;
  Array.Resize(ref parameters, offset + 1);
  parameters[offset] = ret;
  return MakeNewCustomDelegate(parameters);
}
```

**What is profit of that helper if we cannot get a typed delegate to invoke?** See test example below.

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace GenericDelegates {
  static class DelegateCreator {
    public static readonly Func<Type[], Type> MakeNewCustomDelegate = (Func<Type[], Type>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(
      typeof(Func<Type[], Type>),
      typeof(Expression).Assembly.GetType("System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.DelegateHelpers").GetMethod(
        "MakeNewCustomDelegate",
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static
      )
    );
    public static Type NewDelegateType(Type ret, params Type[] parameters) {
      var offset = parameters.Length;
      Array.Resize(ref parameters, offset + 1);
      parameters[offset] = ret;
      return MakeNewCustomDelegate(parameters);
    }
  }
  static class Kernel {
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string name);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr module, string name);
  }
  static class InvokeHelper {
    public static Delegate MakeDelegate(this IntPtr address, Type ret, params Type[] parameters) {
      return Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(address, DelegateCreator.NewDelegateType(ret, parameters));
    }
  }
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      var kernel = Kernel.GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll");
      var address = Kernel.GetProcAddress(kernel, "GetModuleHandleW");
      Console.WriteLine(@"
Module base: 0x{0:X8}
Entry point: 0x{1:X8}
", (int) kernel, (int) address);
      var invoke = address.MakeDelegate(typeof(IntPtr), typeof(string));
      Console.WriteLine(@"
Untyped delegate: {0}
Cast to Invoke: {1}
", invoke, invoke as Func<string, IntPtr> == null ? "Error" : "Valid"); // invoke as Func<string, IntPtr> = NULL
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `What is profit of that helper if we cannot get a typed delegate to invoke?` You don't need a `Func<...>` to be able to invoke the delegate. The `as` operator simply doesn't work that way (casting between classes). Instead, you can use `Delegate.DynamicInvoke`. It's even possible to write a `Func` style generic class as a wrapper around the `Delegate` you create (although there is a lot of boilerplate to match the up-to-16 parameters of `Func`).

Comment: Using such invoke requires to much machine resources:
1. Extra wrapper to call actual delegate;
2. Passing actual paramets to DynamicInvoke via locking them in heap as Objects (even primitive types: byte, int, long, etc).

Comment: It's true that DynamicInvoke is less performant than Invoke, but what I was responding to was the implication that the delegate *cannot* be invoked. Generic delegates like `Func` are better, but they aren't a suitable fit in every situation.

Comment: At heading, I hinted that **no any profit of using** `System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.DelegateHelpers.MakeNewCustomDelegate` to invoke unsafe callbacks on `IntPtr`.

Comment: That is clearly debatable. The cost of `DynamicInvoke` may outweigh the cost of having to maintain separately named non-generic delegates for every required call to `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer`. Just because you don't have a use case for it doesn't mean none exist.

Comment: This is philosophy already, but DynamicInvoke is the bad choice to implementation the invoke of unsafe callbacks in C#. Also, the follows questions like calling convention or marshalling args of  non primitive types can't be resolved via using Generic delegates.

Comment: I have found myself running into this issue again and decided to further investigate. The classes in `System.Reflection.Emit` make it possible to provide delegates (class type derived from `System.MulticastDelegate`) with a generic interface that can be used with P/Invoke, including specifying the calling convention, marshaling behavior, divergent managed and native signatures, and invocation **without** using `DynamicInvoke`. Please see my answer to this question for details on my implementation attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something like that:

```cs
var calculate = FunctionDelegateAccessor.GetMethod<Calculate>(handle, "Calculate");
Console.WriteLine("10 + 10 = " + calculate(10, 10));
var multiply = FunctionDelegateAccessor.GetMethod<Multiply>(handle, "Multiply");
Console.WriteLine("10 * 10 = " + multiply(10, 10));

public delegate int Calculate(int a, int b);
public delegate int Multiply(int a, int b);
```

Output in Console:

```
10 + 10 = 20 
10 * 10 = 100
```

Math.cpp

```cpp
DLL_API int Calculate(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
DLL_API int Multiply(int a, int b)
{
    return a * b;
}
```

Math.h

```cpp
#pragma once

#define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)

extern "C" 
{
    DLL_API int Calculate(int a, int b);
    DLL_API int Multiply(int a, int b);
}
```

```cs
internal static class FunctionDelegateAccessor
{
    public static TDelegate GetMethod<TDelegate>(IntPtr moduleHandle, string name) where TDelegate 
    {
        var methodProcAddress = ExternalKernelCalls.GetProcAddress(moduleHandle, name);
        if (methodProcAddress == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }
        
        var @delegate = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<TDelegate>(methodProcAddress);
        if (@delegate == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Function delegate not found!");
        }
        return @delegate;
    }
}
internal static class ExternalKernelCalls
{
    [DllImport(Kernel32LibraryName, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);
    private const string Kernel32LibraryName = "kernel32.dll";
}
```

More info on the GitHub repo with sources [here](https://github.com/sunnamed434/CysharpInvokesUnmanagedCode).

Answer (score 0):

I was just working on the exact same problem.  Here is the solution I came up with:

```
private T AssignDelegate<T>(string funcName) where T : Delegate
    {
        IntPtr pFuncAddr = KernelFunctions.GetProcAddress(pDll, funcName);
        if(pFuncAddr != IntPtr.Zero)
            return (T)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(
                pFuncAddr, typeof(T));
        else
            return null;
    }//end AssignDelegate
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).